# Proper way of selecting related objects by multiple rows

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Say I have 3 tables: `Houses` has_many `Wardrobes` has_many `Clothes`.

```
houses    wardrobes   clothes
------    ---------   -------
id        id          id
name      house_id    wardrobe_id
          name        name
```

How, having a `House` I can select it's `Wardrobes` which have `jeans` and `shirt` as `Clothes`?

Sample code which doesn't work for apparent reasons:

```
@house.wardrobes.joins(:clothes)
  .where("clothes.name = 'jeans'")
  .where("clothes.name = 'shirt'")
```

Any SQL/ActiveRecord answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to get all wardrobes that have both items of clothing:

```
select w.id, w.house_id
from wardrobes w join
     clothes c
     on c.wardrobe_id = w.id
where c.name in ('jeans', 'shirt')
group by w.id, w.house_id
having count(distinct c.name) = 2;
```

You can filter by the `house_id` in the `where` if you want this only for one house.